# Data overflow instead of hiding

Tags: privacy, websites

I was wondering, if instead of using a private way (like browsing incognito or even using TOR), is it a decent idea to use a program that visits as much random websites as possible (with a bandwidth limit setting of course) what makes it impossible for someone to know what websites the user really visited?

Comment: Frankly speaking, there's so much data going over the internet and it's so growing that I don't think myself there would be need for this. However, if you do a lot of frivolous research and there's something happening near you it's best to hold on. It depends on law what whatever your broadband log of websites is monitored / accesed. If it's school I'd seriously use VPN which is affordable for students. And ISPs are not "holy" themselves nor the Tor exit nodes so it's best to sensibly choose the Broadband or VPN.

Comment: There is browser plugin/extension that generate random traffics and browser user agent. But browser plugin from individual always susceptible to be bought over and hijack by rogue buyer.

Comment: A decent idea to accomplish what, though?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that would help much. Visiting pages randomly (and thus triggering all their ads and trackers) is totally random. Your real browsing, however is not random and follows a pattern - stuff you're interested in, at what times do you open the websites, etc. It would still be easy to tell the signal apart from the noise.

This could work against a small attacker like a site hosting their own ads or a tiny ad network without too much machine nor human time to analyze the data, but given how much money this crappy advertising industry has, the major players like Google and Facebook most likely solved this problem a long time ago.

Comment: I agree, without talking about surveillance ad network already have to distinguish online activities of the different members of the family. The bot would most likely just become one member among the others...

Answer (score 0):

This is thought to be a historically tested method to obscure important information. At least some scholars have suggested that an increase in "noise" prevented the US from being aware of the impending Japanese attack on Pearl Harbor.

Comment: A lot of work has been done to create efficient systems to extract sensible information from huge data set on the Internet (see Google to get an idea!). The fact that the amount of available data is huge does not make it noise anymore. I think that information overflow can be useful only when the user managed to actively reduced data into actual noise by using cryptography.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, what is interesting for authorities is not to know what sites you are visiting in general (this is mainly interesting for marketing services which try to draw a personality scheme from your browsing habits, but there are more effective methods against them).

Authorities are more likely to be interested about a few selected sites you may browse:

- In a totalitarian state, the government may want to know if you are active on social network, if you are visiting activism-related websites, fetching information going against the government propaganda and searching for censorship avoidance resources.
- A more democratic state may want to know if you are regularly looking for any kind of downright illegal activity.

There would two ways to try to overflow surveillance system if useless information:

- Simulate a pure random browsing as stated in your question. But as I explained, this would be useless: you random "overflowing" system may fetch as much kittens and dancing hamster galleries as it wants, it will not manage to hide you when you start looking for information about the Tor browser for instance.
- Simulate random browsing using a selected and updated list of censored / illegal websites matching authorities blacklists. This one would have better chances into masking your actual activity due to all the surrounding noise (if the list matches authorities blacklists, which is not given). However, for life-or-death question or if you expect to remain out of jail, I would *not* recommend this since your simulation software will do nothing but shake a red flag right in front of authorities nose. In other words, most chances are that such "solution" would have a complete opposite effect than the wanted one by drawing authorities' attention on you at a higher scale.

As a side-note, it can be worth noting there are real-life example of solutions trying to go near this second solution, mainly targeting NSA's mass surveillance program.

- There has been a world-wide call encouraging people from all over the world to massively send and post during the same day messages containing keywords assumed to be on NSA's keyword lists in order to overflow their systems. I do not remember the exact date, after a quick search I could only this [Operation troll the NSA](http://trollthensa.com/) webpage but I'm quite sure this is not the original one and is just inspired from an older pre-Snowden "Prism" era operation.

  However, given the massive and multi-layer nature of the NSA's technology, I'm quite doubtful if such operation are really effective.
- During my search I also found-out this [browser plugin](https://flagger.io/) allowing you to automatically insert blacklisted keywords in your URLs while you are browsing the web.

  Obviously, for these keywords to be detectable on the wire you should browse HTTP unencrypted website, as SSL/TLS would hide your request. IMO this would be a far worse practice from a privacy perspective.

There is still one area where your overflow idea still remains valid, not to say recommended: if you are using privacy protection tools such as encryption, anonymous browsing, etc., do not reserve these tools only for sensitive activities. For instance, would you need to fetch the latest kitten galleries, use Tor to do this. This way, it will not be possible to link the mere fact that you are using Tor to some repressed activity (for instance it will not be possible to precisely correlate your Tor activity frequency with some activist blog updates). The same way encrypt sensitive and non-sensitive mails, encrypt disks and not files, etc (there was even projects designed to send encrypted emails to random addresses).

Combined with cryptography-based privacy tool, this works because cryptography keeps the authorities from being able to directly access you data, they cannot directly extract interesting content anymore, they are left with meta-data analysis. Information overflow comes as a second layer to try to protect against this meta-data analysis.

IMO, information overflow, if used, should only be used as such a second layer. See Google for instance to get an idea how current IT infrastructures are strong in terms of filtering noise to find the needle in the haystack.

So, while you ask "Data overflow *instead* of hiding", my answer would be to use both, or: "hide first, *then* use data overflow to conceal what you are hiding".

Comment: Do you happen to have references to "projects designed to send encrypted emails to random addresses"? If a sufficiently large number of people on the Internet send out such (dummy or not) encrypted stuffs, the computers of the surveillance agencies would be overloaded in attempting to decrypt them IMHO.

Comment: @Mok-KongShen: The goal with this system was less to overload surveillance agencies with encrypted emails, but more to prevent them to list your contacts and build relation-maps of who communicates with who. IIRC I crossed this idea in some early discussion for the [Own Mailbox](https://www.own-mailbox.com/) project, but one of the challenge here as I see it is to avoid to become blacklisted as spam sender and become unable to send legitimate emails.

Comment: Thanks for the informations. I may nonetheless repeat that IMHO one "conceivable" means of overloading the computers of surveillance agencies is that a sufficiently large number of the common people, independent of whether there is need of encryption or not, always attach to their emails some lines of hexs that anyway look like the results of encryption. However, for that to work, there need to be a large number of persons who voluntarily do a tiny little bit of additional work in sending emails but common people are simply too lazy to do that. Hence, sadly, that idea can't be practical.